# Magento Multi-Store - Seperate IP for each Admin?

Tags: multistore, m2e

Is it possible to have a multi-store setup, in which the admin area for each store utilizes a separate IP address for each domain?

For example:

**Dedicated Server - 1 Magento Install**

- **Domain1.com/admin = 1.1.1.1**
- **Domain2.com/admin = 2.2.2.2**

The reason is to use an extension such as M2E to push products to Ebay, etc. - but would like each store's "push" to come from a seperate IP address.  (e.g., onc domain cannot be traced back to the other).  It's a requirement that nobody can know the 2 domains are the same company.

Would it be easier to create 2 separate Magento installs? If so, how could we synchronize the inventory from one to the other?

Comment: what is your reason to have separate ip?

Comment: Because that is the requirement from the company.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multi site instance with 2 IP adddresses](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/110625/multi-site-instance-with-2-ip-adddresses)