# Multi site instance with 2 IP adddresses

Tags: magento-1.9, multistore, magento-community, ssl

We're adding a second storefront to our existing Magento instance. The two store fronts will be accessed by different domain names and would have to have separate IP address to differentiate the payment charges on the customer's CC (so I am told by Authorize.net) and add SSL certificate to both.

My server support has no idea how to point a different domain name over to the magento instance since it's on a different IP address and the hosting company support team has said it can't be done. **I am being told to build a new Magento instance**, but I find that hard to believe. There must be other multisite instances on different IP addresses.

What are some **best practices to architect multisite** Magento from multiple IP addresses?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set up second store in multi-domain configuration?](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/8359/how-to-set-up-second-store-in-multi-domain-configuration)

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to have multiple IP addresses on one server which share the same document root, so if your hoster insists that it cannot be done it is a limitation of them and you should find another hoster.

Comment: I will approach them again. Is there anything I can do from PLESK to set it up? (I understand that this is now getting further from a Magento question)

Comment: I would have to look it up myself but I'm sure that you can do it with Plesk, given that the hoster assigned you a second IP.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a DNS issue:

- point your domain name to this ip address
- add this domain name to base url of your store view
- add store code to .htaccess

check that duplicate question for more info.

and thats it.

Comment: If I point the second domain name to the first IP address, will that coutneract having a second IP address for SSL in the first place?

Comment: ssl doesnt care about ip, it checks domain name...